Ordering by ascending using LISTAGG
I am still very new to SQL and have seen many questions but I have not seen any answers to help me get my results. I have a query that I need to order the column REFDES in ascending order. Any help will be much appreciated. In the picture I provided you can see the REFDES column is not in ascending order.

      WITH DistinctRefDes AS (
    SELECT bom.PINBR,
           bom.PITR,
           bom.CINBR,
           bom.CITR,
           REPLACE(TRIM(bom.REFDES), ',', '') AS REFDES
    FROM FILTD.PREFP110 bom
    WHERE TRIM(bom.REFDES) <> ''
    GROUP BY bom.PINBR,
             bom.PITR,
             bom.CINBR,
             bom.CITR,
             REPLACE(TRIM(bom.REFDES), ',', '')
    ),
    OrderedRefDes AS (
    SELECT PINBR,
           PITR,
           CINBR,
           CITR,
           REFDES
    FROM DistinctRefDes
    ORDER BY REFDES
    ),
    DistinctRefDes2 AS (
    SELECT PINBR,
           PITR,
           CINBR,
           CITR,
           LISTAGG(REFDES, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY REFDES) AS REFDES
    FROM OrderedRefDes
    GROUP BY PINBR,
             PITR,
             CINBR,
             CITR
    )
    SELECT bom.PINBR                            AS "PNumber",
       i2.ITDSC                             AS "PName",
       bom.PITR                             AS "PRev",
       bom.CINBR                            AS "CNumber",
       itmrva.ITDSC                         AS "CDesc",
       bom.CITR                             AS "CRev",
       bom.QTYPR                            AS "Qty",
       COALESCE(DistinctRefDes2.REFDES, '') AS REFDES,
       itembl.MOHTQ
    FROM AMFLIBD.PSTDTL bom
    LEFT JOIN DistinctRefDes2
       ON bom.PINBR = DistinctRefDes2.PINBR
       AND bom.PITR = DistinctRefDes2.PITR
       AND bom.CINBR = DistinctRefDes2.CINBR
       AND bom.CITR = DistinctRefDes2.CITR
    LEFT JOIN AMFLIBD.ITMRVA itmrva
       ON bom.CINBR = itmrva.ITNBR AND bom.CITR = itmrva.ITRV
    LEFT JOIN AMFLIBD.ITMRVA i2
       ON bom.PINBR = i2.ITNBR AND bom.PITR = i2.ITRV
    LEFT JOIN AMFLIBD.ITEMBL itembl
       ON bom.CINBR = itembl.ITNBR AND itembl.HOUSE = 'MVS'
    WHERE bom.PINBR = '980-218130-106'
    AND bom.PITR = 'B'
    ORDER BY bom.CINBR;


To order by REFDES too, do ORDER BY bom.CINBR, REFDES.

adding REFDES to the order by didnt change the results.

Do you find the ORDER BY REFDES result better? (At the final end. ORDER BY in subqueries makes no difference.)

I added it to the end and received the same results.

Show us some sample table data in the current order, and in the desired order. Use properly formatted text (not images, not links to images.)

A [mcve] is always a great start when asking for SQL assistance. (Where minimal is emphasized.)

Heres how I want my results R12, R15, R29, R85..heres what I am getting R85, R12, R29, R85

Show us a consistent, minimized [mcve]. Your query returns 9 columns, but your comment above just mentions a few values.

I am sorry, Im not strong with SQL to break this down. I believe one issue to the query is I am combining 3 records in the DB2 database and then trying to order their values. This is why I am using distinct. I believe the 3 separate records are setting the order for the REFDES column. I would also like to have REFDES separated by commas but I was able to get those results in SSRS/
